# How to prove Chebyshev–Gauss quadrature integrate polynomial of degree less than $2n-1$ exactly

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

What I want to ask is mentioned in the title.

For example: how can we show that $\int_{-1}^1\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\frac{\pi}{5}\left(f(0)+f(\cos{\frac{3\pi}{10}})+f(\cos{\frac{5\pi}{10}})+f(\cos{\frac{7\pi}{10}})+f(\cos{\frac{9\pi}{10}})\right)$ is exact for all polynomials of degree 9.

If someone can explain to me how do we even get the weight and nodes formula as stated in Wikipedia, I would really appreciate that!

To check formula, please follow here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%E2%80%93Gauss_quadrature

Comment: This problem was answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4415248/prove-that-int-11-fracfx-sqrt1-x2dx-frac-pin-sum-k-0n

Answer (score 0):

One needs to solve a moment problem:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem